# Is Moneris Direct Post Secure?

Tags: security

I am looking at the Moneris Payment Processing and their **Direct Post** method.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how the security on it works.

As best as I can tell it does this:

1. Web User comes to my site.  They fill out their credit card information (https).
2. I show them a summary in a form.  When they hit submit they go to Moneris (POST) - including my ID, credit card info, and a custom **Transaction ID**.
3. Moneris processes the transaction and sends them back to my site (as a POST)
4. If they arrive on `failed.php` or whatever URL you specify, the transaction failed.  Else:
5. If they arrive on `gotyourmoney.php` then the transaction seemingly worked.  Time to validate.  (included in POST vars is a **Unique ID** for the transaction, **date/time stamps**, **response_code** (got money, didn't get money) and a few other miscellaneous items.
6. I redirect the user back to the moneris site with another POST.  I include my ID again and the **Unique ID** returned in **step 5** to verify the transaction.
7. User is redirected back to `gotyourmoney_verified.php` as a POST again with the **unique ID**, **Transaction ID**, and **response_code**.

**What I can't figure out is this:**

No where does there seem to be *any* information that I can validate that the web user can't just make up.  Even though it is an https connection I'm trusting the user to pass all information.  They could immediately go to the `gotyourmoney.php` page and never even go to the moneris payment gateway.  They can just make up the ID's.  When I send them back to moneris for the transaction verification, again they could just post a made-up response to my site.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed since all of those things go through the client, they can easily be spoofed.  And the Moneris documentation doesn't tell you this.  You need some sort of server-to-server step to be sure that everything is in order.

I would suggest doing a preauthorization using the hosted pay page and then doing a capture with the PHP API.  Since you're doing the capture server-to-server, any attempt to spoof by the client will just result in a failed capture.

Comment: Thanks Jason!  That is what I thought - I just couldn't figure out why they would allow you to do it that way.

Answer (score 3):

The Transaction Verification feature of DirectPost can be used to prevent spoofing.

Here's how it works

1. A customer enters their credit card information on your site and the information is sent to Moneris for processing
2. Moneris processes the transaction and sends the transaction result to your site
3. If transaction verification is enabled then there will be a special field in the transaction result called a "transaction key"
4. Then to verify that the transaction wasn't spoofed, your site would send the transaction key in a transaction verification request to Moneris
5. Moneris would then verify the transaction using the transaction key and respond with a result that lets you know if the transaction was spoofed

The Integration Guide for DirectPost has all the details on how to implement the Transaction Verification feature and can be download at http://developer.moneris.com (free registration required).

In addition to Transaction Verification you can also setup a referrer URL. If a referrer URL is setup then Moneris will verify if the transaction is coming from an allowed URL. It's possible to circumvent the referrer URL feature but having a referrer URL enabled is still useful as part of a defense in depth strategy because it makes it that much harder to spoof a transaction.